# Creating a bidimensional array with Spark (pyspark)

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark

Working with Python 2.7 in Spark,
I have two lists of points in 2 dimensions. List *A* has *n* points and list *B* has *m* points. 
Each point is represented by a list of 2 elements (x and y coordinates):

```
set_a = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ..., [xn, yn]]
set_b = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ..., [xm, ym]]
```

I would like to build a `n*m` matrix *M* where the generic element `M[i][j]` contains the distance between the point in *A* with index *i* and the point in *B* with index *j*. I'm not talking about the euclidean distance, but I have my `personal_distance_function(point_a, point_b)` which I would like to use for the building of *M*.

In pure Python 2.7 I'm currently doing something like this:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B)):
        M[i, j] = personal_distance_function(A[i], B[j])
```

... but since I need to do this with pyspark, do you have any suggestion on how to do it using SparkContext?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert your lists into dataframes:

```
>>> df_a = spark.createDataFrame(set_a, ['a_x', 'a_y'])
>>> df_b = spark.createDataFrame(set_b, ['b_x', 'b_y'])
```

Then you need to create an UDF (user defined function) to register your function in spark:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
>>> dist = udf(personal_distance_function, DoubleType())
```

Finally, you can use simple spark code to cross-join both dataframes and execute a distance function on them:

```
>>> df_a.crossJoin(df_b) \
      .withColumn('dist', dist(struct('a_x', 'a_y'), struct('b_x', 'b_y'))).show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't get something: where do i get "spark" object for creating data frame? I tried to instanciate SparkContext, but it says that no createDataFrame() method is defined.

Comment: `spark` is reference to spark context, available for versions >=2.0 in `pyspark` shell. If you are using spark < 2.0, replace `spark` with `sqlContext`